# How can i instantiate many times a activity which set flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK ?

Tags: android

My application have a service and an activity. Sometimes the service will send a broadcast, if my activity receive the broadcast, i will start the activity and show a dialog. But if i need to start an activity successfully in onReceiver(), i must set flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for the activity, and the activity only could be instantiated once, if i start the activity again, it couldn't be instantiated again. I can show other message of service when my appliaction have show the activity yet.

How can i start a some activity many times in onReceiver()?

Comment: Your problem isn't clearly stated. What do you mean 'it couldnt be instantiated again'? Show your logcat or post code snippets to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK, the flag would start a new activity in any case.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like about different OS version, it will start activity successfully on some version (2.3.7), my device's OS version is 2.3.3 when the activity is added flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.